# Query a DataExtensionObject on the business unit level

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, c#

This is the code I have:

```
APIObject[] results;

RetrieveRequest rr = new RetrieveRequest {
    ObjectType = "DataExtensionObject[" + "NameOfDataExtension" + "]",
    Properties = new string[] {
        "prop1", "prop2", "prop3"
    },
    Options = new RetrieveOptions { 
        Client = new ClientID { ID = Settings.BusinessUnitId, IDSpecified = true}
    } 
};
SimpleFilterPart filter = new SimpleFilterPart();
filter.Property = "EmailAddress";
filter.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals;
filter.Value = new[] { "email@email.com" };

rr.Filter = filter;

string requestID;

Client.GetClient().Retrieve(rr, out requestID, out results);
```

"results" variable always comes back empty. I know the code works because when I remove the retrieve options and create a data extension of the same name on the primary business unit it works fine. I know the ID is correct because I'm able to post to data extensions as well as post and get from publication lists with the same ID

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to remove the double-quotes from around the `NameOfDataExtension` -- assuming it's a variable:

```
APIObject[] results;

RetrieveRequest rr = new RetrieveRequest {
    ObjectType = "DataExtensionObject[" + NameOfDataExtension + "]",
    Properties = new string[] {
        "prop1", "prop2", "prop3"
    },
    Options = new RetrieveOptions { 
        Client = new ClientID { ID = Settings.BusinessUnitId, IDSpecified = true}
    } 
};
SimpleFilterPart filter = new SimpleFilterPart();
filter.Property = "EmailAddress";
filter.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals;
filter.Value = new[] { "email@email.com" };

rr.Filter = filter;

string requestID;

Client.GetClient().Retrieve(rr, out requestID, out results);
```